# Wait for all child thread to finish (in C)

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

Code first

```
while(running)
{
    memset(&tcp_client, 0, tcp_client_len);

    FD_ZERO(&readFDs);
    FD_SET(tcp_server_s, &readFDs);
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    if(select(0, &readFDs, NULL, NULL, &tv))
    {
        if( (tcp_client_s = accept(tcp_server_s, (struct sockaddr *)&tcp_client,&tcp_client_len)) == INVALID_SOCKET )
        {
            cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_ERROR, "(%d) accept() failed\n", WSAGetLastError());
            continue;
        }
        cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_COMM, "(%s:%d) accepted connection\n", inet_ntoa(tcp_client.sin_addr), ntohs(tcp_client.sin_port));

        CreateThread(NULL, 0, tcp_thread, (LPVOID)tcp_client_s, 0, NULL);
    }
}
```

This is part of my TCP threads handler. What i would like to know is how to make it wait for all his child thread to finish before exiting when not `running` anymore (CTRL+C signal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Maintain a list of `HANDLE`s containing the handles of the successfully created threads (a `HANDLE` is the result of [`CreateThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if successful).
2. Use [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to join on each of the threads prior to application exit.

Comment: What happens if i pass a `HANDLE` list containing already closed thread handles to `WaitForMultipleObjects()`?

Comment: The documentation states: _If one of these handles is closed while the wait is still pending, the function's behavior is undefined._ It isn't clear if that includes closed on entry to the function. I would recommend removing it from the list.